# select different id with number in the name

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following Javascript file:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

     $( "#registry_donations_attributes_.0-9_data_donazione" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();

});
```

I would take all the id that follow this rule:

```
#registry_donations_attributes_0_data_donazione
#registry_donations_attributes_1_data_donazione
#registry_donations_attributes_2_data_donazione
#registry_donations_attributes_3_data_donazione
                        ...
#registry_donations_attributes_n_data_donazione
```

I tried `"#registry_donations_attributes_.0-9_data_donazione"` but it doen't work. I don't know jquery very well. Thank You.

Comment: Why you don't use class instead and then select all the elements of this class?

Comment: can't , i need to use id. i'm using a framework and i need to have this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JQuery selectors do not support regex patterns, which is apparently the way you want to specify the pattern for the id naming.

What you specify instead are elements with the id `registry_donations_attributes_` that have the css class `0-9_data_donazione`, which does not make much sense in this context (which shouldn't make you feel bas, selector syntax can be intricate).

If possible, assign a common css class ( like `_data_donazione` ) to the elements and use the selector as follows: `$("._data_donazione")`.

Alternatively, use a combination of attribute prefix and suffix selector (not recommended; to be painstakingly correct you'd have to check for the number part of the id anyway):

```
$("*[id^='registry_donations_attributes_'][id$='_data_donazione]")
```

Answer (score 0):

why don't you use a for loop?...

```
n = 10;
for (var x = 0; x < n; x++){
    $( "#registry_donations_attributes_" + x + "_data_donazione").datepicker({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd' }).val();
}
```

Comment: are you able to assign a class to these elements or do you not have control over that?

Comment: i can't assign , sorry

Answer (score 0):

The best you can do in a straight jQuery selector is to combine the [starts with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) and [ends with](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-ends-with-selector/) attribute selectors.

```js
var items = $("[id^='registry_donations_attributes_'][id$='_data_donazione']");
console.log(items.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="registry_donations_attributes_0_data_donazione"></div>
<div id="registry_donations_attributes_1_data_donazione"></div>
<div id="registry_donations_attributes_2_data_donazione"></div>
<div id="not"></div>
```

Alternatively you could use a filter with a regular expression

```js
var items = $("*").filter(function() {
  return this.id.match(/registry_donations_attributes_\d*_data_donazione/);
});
console.log(items.toArray());
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="registry_donations_attributes_0_data_donazione"></div>
<div id="registry_donations_attributes_1_data_donazione"></div>
<div id="registry_donations_attributes_2_data_donazione"></div>
<div id="not"></div>
```